# How can i use google drive using cron with python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, google-drive-api

i try program a cron that writing  a file in a user's google drive, but i don't know how i can authorize my application to write in this google drive. I try:

```
    SCOPE = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope = SCOPE)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
    service = build("storage", "v1beta1", http=http, developerKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Always the response is "Not authorized".

Comment: In case you haven't already done so, you should probably remove your developer key, or replace with some characters. I dont know if it really is a security risk, but better to be safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

http://www.maketecheasier.com/access-sync-google-drive-in-ubuntu/2012/06/06 you cud try this article incase its what you are looking for. hope it helps